# Xcode 4: Source Control options grayed out (Git local repository)

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

When I set up a new project in Xcode 4, and select "Create local git repository for this project," all seems well enough. I'm able to commit files from the Organizer (it would appear.) However, in the Project Manager, the "Source Control" menu options (commit, etc.) are all grayed out, except for "Repositories" which of course just takes me to the organizer.

Furthermore, in the Project Manager window, I don't see any icons by file names indicating if they're changed, committed etc. like I see in the screenshots in the Xcode 4 documentation.

I've tried this with both a project that's connected to Github, and one that's just using a local repository, and I've still yet to see those options not be grayed out. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem, however I did not save my files in the /Developer folder.  Has anyone else had this problem and found another cause/solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the cause of this problem is that I was saving projects in /Developer.

Turns out, that's a big no-no. Not only does it break git integration in the way described in the original question, as well as breaking other features such as Xcode 4's refactoring functionality, it also runs the risk of deleting all of your work when you install an update. Once I started saving projects outside of /Developer, all the git functions in Xcode 4 started working as expected.

Bottom line: Don't keep projects in /Developer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit confusing.  Apples documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Has a great way to activate the source control via the command line:

**To set up a Git repository from the command line . . .**

1. Use the **cd** command to switch to your project folder, making it the current working directory.
2. Enter **git init** to create an empty repository.
3. Enter **git add .** to copy your project files into the repository.
4. Enter **git commit -m "Initial commit."** to commit all the files.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've been able to commit files from the command line and from the organizer, that part is not a problem. The problem is that I'm not able to commit from the Project Manager window (the "Source Control" menu options there are all grayed out.